# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'tblSQLAdminInventory' to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server

Some of my previous questions may now make sense...  Anyway, here's what I have:

```
create table ##NewTemp1       
            (
                [TableName] [nvarchar](100), 
                [UniqueName] [nvarchar](100), 
                [FieldName] [nvarchar](100), 
                [TransID_80079] [nvarchar](2000), 
                [TransID_80080] [nvarchar](2000)
            )

INSERT INTO ##NewTemp1 
SELECT X.TableName, X.UniqueName, X.FieldName, X.TransID_80079, X.TransID_80080 
FROM (
  SELECT * FROM ##Temp1175443 UNION 
  SELECT * FROM ##Temp2175443 UNION 
  SELECT * FROM ##Temp3175443 UNION 
... etc ...
  SELECT * FROM ##Temp22175443 UNION 
  SELECT * FROM ##Temp23175443 UNION 
  SELECT 1 AS TableName, 1 AS UniqueName, 1 AS FieldName, 1 AS TransID_80079, 1 AS TransID_80080 WHERE 1=0
) X
```

I'm getting this:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Conversion failed when converting
>   the varchar value 'tblSQLAdminInventory' to data type int.

I purposely, specifically set up a temp table with nvarchar fields so that all values would be written to nvarchar fields.  Why is it even mentioning an int data type?   Can anyone help?

Comment: what column types you have in ##Temp1175443?

Comment: SELECT 1 AS TableName, 1 AS UniqueName, 1 AS FieldName, 1 AS TransID_80079, 1 AS TransID_80080 WHERE 1=0

Comment: You should use `union all` rather than `union`, unless you really intend to incur the overhead of removing duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try single quotes in your last select statement:

```
SELECT '1' AS TableName, '1' AS UniqueName, '1' AS FieldName, '1' AS TransID_80079, '1' AS TransID_80080
```

Also consider dropping the WHERE 1=0 or modifying it with single quotes as well.

Those are the only instances of INT that I can see in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Try using quotes around the numbers in the last row:

```
  SELECT '1' AS TableName, '1' AS UniqueName, '1' AS FieldName, '1' AS TransID_80079, '1' AS TransID_80080
```

The `union` has complicated rules for determining the type and it is probably deciding that columns should be numbers when they are really strings.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Gordon.  You and the n00b answered at almost the same time, I figured you wouldn't miss the +15 but that he/she could use it.  :o)